# do signals such as post_delete get included in the initiating delete transaction

Tags: python, django

I have two models related by models.OneToOneField. I am using to post_delete signal to remove the related object. Are both these deletes included in the one transaction by default? If not how would I make sure they are.

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Owner)
def post_delete_owner(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.address:
        instance.address.delete()
```

Comment: Just curious, why not use `on_delete=CASCADE` for the one to one relation?

Comment: That's going to be in an upcoming refactor. Do not want to change the model at present.

Comment: If this is triggered from handling a request, by default it will not be in a single transaction. But you can enable atomic request using [ATOMIC_REQUESTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-ATOMIC_REQUESTS) setting